# Programmable WebCrawler with C#

Tags: c#, web-crawler, data-extraction

I would like to extract specific data form a known Url : from html tags like span, a, divs ... !
So I'm searching for an existing library for a WebCrawler written in C# ! ... or maybe any other idea.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For parsing HTML, you might want to look into the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  As for grabbing the HTML from a website, you can use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).

Comment: I would like to parse HTML with C# just like we do with DOM !
Like for every Div Having the specific class name I would like to get text form child span or a or any other tags !

Comment: @Aladdin Gallas I'm not sure what you mean...HTML Agility Pack ****can**** parse HTML.

Comment: @NickAldwin : If HTMLAgilityPack can do that, I just need an example ! Thank you so much for Helping me

Comment: @Aladdin Gallas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack

Comment: @Aladdin Gallas if you have a specific question about using Html Agility Pack, ask it separately on SO.

Comment: Thank you so much NickAldwin. I have to test it before and if I have issues I'll told you.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://blog.abodit.com/2010/03/a-simple-web-crawler-in-c-using-htmlagilitypack/) guy wrote an article on using HtmlAgilityPack for web crawling from C#, and [this](http://code.google.com/p/spiderframework/) is a framework for web crawling, though the project seems to be dead, you can look at them and see if they fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people on SO like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).